# catch exceptionorg.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure

Tags: apache-spark

I am running my code in production and it runs successfully most of the time but some times it fails with following error:

```
catch exceptionorg.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 14 in stage 9.1 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 14.3 in stage 9.1 (TID 3825, xxxprd0painod02.xxxprd.local): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data03/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_xxxxxxx012345_70120/blockmgr-97546ecd-567d-4451-91dd-762744aadc2b/1e/temp_shuffle_fb43319d-8cec-43e1-b7f8-cda30410d36c (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried to change the executor memory to make sure that we have enough memory but still facing the same issue.

Any thoughts on how we can resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Bab

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the error messages, seems like problem with data/file stored in blocks. Try to refresh meta data or try to restore file again, as may be file corrupted may solve your problem. Post your code if not able to solve the problem.

It has nothing deal with memory.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am reading around 2M data from elasticsearch and doing some joins with other small tables to grab some data from those tables and finally writing into hive tables. While writing to hive table its creating 5600 tasks and some times while doing these inserts, job is failing with above mentioned error message. I am reading 2M rows but after joining with other tables and doing group by, it is coming to around 40 to 50 rows.

Comment: But error logs doesn't say anything about memory. I have similar kind of issue in past and able to solve the problem by invalidating metadata of hive table.

Comment: Here is the code I am using to insert data into hive table - Final_DF.repartition(3).write.mode("append").partitionBy("key").insertInto(DBName + "." + tblName). So where do we need to run invalidate medata? I think this will run for impala to access hive tables right?

Comment: Use the refresh statement to load the latest metastore metadata and block location data for a particular table in these scenarios: After loading new data files into the HDFS data directory for the table. After data insertion in hive table using sparksql you can refresh metadata with statement >spark.catalog.refreshTable("my_table").

Comment: I have applied this to my code and will wait and see couple of days and update you. Thank you for your help...